# Conditional filtering and data transformation in R; removing rows and adding additional columns based on group and value

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I am trying to transform an existing dataset by filtering out rows that I no longer need based on condition and by group. Subsequently, I would like to add additional column which essentially is a status column and an activity instance column. Here is the dataframe:-

```
rawdata<-structure(list(DateTime = c("20/02/2021 13:00", "20/02/2021 14:00", 
                                     "20/02/2021 15:00", "20/02/2021 16:00", "20/02/2021 17:00", "20/02/2021 18:00", 
                                     "20/02/2021 19:00", "20/02/2021 20:00", "20/02/2021 21:00", "20/02/2021 22:00", 
                                     "20/02/2021 23:00", "21/02/2021 00:00", "01/03/2021 00:00", "01/03/2021 01:00", 
                                     "01/03/2021 02:00", "01/03/2021 03:00", "01/03/2021 04:00", "01/03/2021 05:00", 
                                     "01/03/2021 06:00", "01/03/2021 07:00", "01/03/2021 08:00", "01/03/2021 09:00", 
                                     "01/03/2021 10:00", "01/03/2021 11:00", "01/03/2021 12:00", "01/03/2021 13:00", 
                                     "20/02/2021 13:00", "20/02/2021 14:00", "20/02/2021 15:00", "20/02/2021 16:00", 
                                     "20/02/2021 17:00", "20/02/2021 18:00", "20/02/2021 19:00", "20/02/2021 20:00", 
                                     "20/02/2021 21:00", "20/02/2021 22:00"), Cluster = c("Cluster 3", 
                                                                                          "Cluster 3", "Cluster 3", "Cluster 3", "NotActive", "NotActive", 
                                                                                          "NotActive", "Cluster 2", "Cluster 1", "Cluster 3", "NotActive", 
                                                                                          "NotActive", "NotActive", "Cluster 5", "Cluster 5", "Cluster 4", 
                                                                                          "NotActive", "NotActive", "NotActive", "NotActive", "Cluster 2", 
                                                                                          "Cluster 2", "Cluster 3", "NotActive", "NotActive", "NotActive", 
                                                                                          "NotActive", "NotActive", "NotActive", "NotActive", "NotActive", 
                                                                                          "NotActive", "Cluster 1", "Cluster 2", "NotActive", "NotActive"
                                     ), UserID = c("AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", 
                                                   "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", 
                                                   "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", 
                                                   "BBB", "DDD", "DDD", "DDD", "DDD", "DDD", "DDD", "DDD", "DDD", 
                                                   "DDD", "DDD")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L))
print(rawdata)
           DateTime   Cluster UserID
           DateTime   Cluster UserID
1  20/02/2021 13:00 Cluster 3    AAA
2  20/02/2021 14:00 Cluster 3    AAA
3  20/02/2021 15:00 Cluster 3    AAA
4  20/02/2021 16:00 Cluster 3    AAA
5  20/02/2021 17:00 NotActive    AAA
6  20/02/2021 18:00 NotActive    AAA
7  20/02/2021 19:00 NotActive    AAA
8  20/02/2021 20:00 Cluster 2    AAA
9  20/02/2021 21:00 Cluster 1    AAA
10 20/02/2021 22:00 Cluster 3    AAA
11 20/02/2021 23:00 NotActive    AAA
12 21/02/2021 00:00 NotActive    AAA
13 01/03/2021 00:00 NotActive    AAA
14 01/03/2021 01:00 Cluster 5    BBB
15 01/03/2021 02:00 Cluster 5    BBB
16 01/03/2021 03:00 Cluster 4    BBB
17 01/03/2021 04:00 NotActive    BBB
18 01/03/2021 05:00 NotActive    BBB
19 01/03/2021 06:00 NotActive    BBB
20 01/03/2021 07:00 NotActive    BBB
21 01/03/2021 08:00 Cluster 2    BBB
22 01/03/2021 09:00 Cluster 2    BBB
23 01/03/2021 10:00 Cluster 3    BBB
24 01/03/2021 11:00 NotActive    BBB
25 01/03/2021 12:00 NotActive    BBB
26 01/03/2021 13:00 NotActive    BBB
27 20/02/2021 13:00 NotActive    DDD
28 20/02/2021 14:00 NotActive    DDD
29 20/02/2021 15:00 NotActive    DDD
30 20/02/2021 16:00 NotActive    DDD
31 20/02/2021 17:00 NotActive    DDD
32 20/02/2021 18:00 NotActive    DDD
33 20/02/2021 19:00 Cluster 1    DDD
34 20/02/2021 20:00 Cluster 2    DDD
35 20/02/2021 21:00 NotActive    DDD
36 20/02/2021 22:00 NotActive    DDD
```

And for further explanation, here is the desired output:-

```
desiredoutput<-structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1613826000, 1613829600, 
                                                     1613833200, 1613836800, 1613840400, 1613851200, 1613854800, 1613858400, 
                                                     1613862000, 1614560400, 1614564000, 1614567600, 1614571200, 1614585600, 
                                                     1614589200, 1614592800, 1614596400, 1613847600, 1613851200, 1613854800
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Cluster = c("Cluster 3", 
                                                               "Cluster 3", "Cluster 3", "Cluster 3", "NotActive", "Cluster 2", 
                                                               "Cluster 1", "Cluster 3", "NotActive", "Cluster 5", "Cluster 5", 
                                                               "Cluster 4", "NotActive", "Cluster 2", "Cluster 2", "Cluster 3", 
                                                               "NotActive", "Cluster 1", "Cluster 2", "NotActive"), UserID = c("AAA", 
                                                                                                                               "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "BBB", 
                                                                                                                               "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "DDD", "DDD", 
                                                                                                                               "DDD"), Status = c("Start", "Ongoing", "Ongoing", "Ongoing", 
                                                                                                                                                  "Complete", "Start", "Ongoing", "Ongoing", "Complete", "Start", 
                                                                                                                                                  "Ongoing", "Ongoing", "Complete", "Start", "Ongoing", "Ongoing", 
                                                                                                                                                  "Complete", "Start", "Ongoing", "Complete"), Instance = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                            2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

print(desiredoutput)
      DateTime            Cluster   UserID Status   Instance
   <dttm>              <chr>     <chr>  <chr>       <dbl>
 1 2021-02-20 13:00:00 Cluster 3 AAA    Start           1
 2 2021-02-20 14:00:00 Cluster 3 AAA    Ongoing         2
 3 2021-02-20 15:00:00 Cluster 3 AAA    Ongoing         3
 4 2021-02-20 16:00:00 Cluster 3 AAA    Ongoing         4
 5 2021-02-20 17:00:00 NotActive AAA    Complete        5
 6 2021-02-20 20:00:00 Cluster 2 AAA    Start           1
 7 2021-02-20 21:00:00 Cluster 1 AAA    Ongoing         2
 8 2021-02-20 22:00:00 Cluster 3 AAA    Ongoing         3
 9 2021-02-20 23:00:00 NotActive AAA    Complete        4
10 2021-03-01 01:00:00 Cluster 5 BBB    Start           1
11 2021-03-01 02:00:00 Cluster 5 BBB    Ongoing         2
12 2021-03-01 03:00:00 Cluster 4 BBB    Ongoing         3
13 2021-03-01 04:00:00 NotActive BBB    Complete        4
14 2021-03-01 08:00:00 Cluster 2 BBB    Start           1
15 2021-03-01 09:00:00 Cluster 2 BBB    Ongoing         2
16 2021-03-01 10:00:00 Cluster 3 BBB    Ongoing         3
17 2021-03-01 11:00:00 NotActive BBB    Complete        4
18 2021-02-20 19:00:00 Cluster 1 DDD    Start           1
19 2021-02-20 20:00:00 Cluster 2 DDD    Ongoing         2
20 2021-02-20 21:00:00 NotActive DDD    Complete        3
```

What I am after is that in the `Cluster` column (by `UserID`), if the value says `NotActive`, keep the first `NotActive` value and discard the remaining `NotActive` rows until it is something else. As well, I would like to create a "Status" column, where the first value in this column corresponds to `Start`, until the first `NotActive` value, which will correspond to `Complete`; everything else in between `Ongoing`. Lastly, the `Instance` column is just numerated from 1==Start to N==Complete in the `Status` column.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` way -

```
library(dplyr)

rawdata %>%
  #for each user id
  group_by(UserID) %>%
  #drop the repeated the 'NotActive' rows
  filter(Cluster != 'NotActive' | lag(Cluster != 'NotActive', default = TRUE)) %>%
  #Drop the rows that begins with 'NotActive'. 
  filter(!(row_number() == 1 & Cluster == 'NotActive')) %>%
  #Create a group column for each cycle
  group_by(grp = cumsum(lag(Cluster == 'NotActive', default = TRUE)), .add = TRUE) %>%
  #Create a status column which starts with 'Start' and ends with 'Complete'
  #fill it with 'Ongoing' in between. 
  #Create an Instance column using row_number()
  mutate(Status = c('Start', rep('Ongoing', n() - 2), 'Complete'), 
         Instance = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)
```

This returns the following dataframe.

```
#   DateTime         Cluster   UserID Status   Instance
#   <chr>            <chr>     <chr>  <chr>       <int>
# 1 20/02/2021 13:00 Cluster 3 AAA    Start           1
# 2 20/02/2021 14:00 Cluster 3 AAA    Ongoing         2
# 3 20/02/2021 15:00 Cluster 3 AAA    Ongoing         3
# 4 20/02/2021 16:00 Cluster 3 AAA    Ongoing         4
# 5 20/02/2021 17:00 NotActive AAA    Complete        5
# 6 20/02/2021 20:00 Cluster 2 AAA    Start           1
# 7 20/02/2021 21:00 Cluster 1 AAA    Ongoing         2
# 8 20/02/2021 22:00 Cluster 3 AAA    Ongoing         3
# 9 20/02/2021 23:00 NotActive AAA    Complete        4
#10 01/03/2021 01:00 Cluster 5 BBB    Start           1
#11 01/03/2021 02:00 Cluster 5 BBB    Ongoing         2
#12 01/03/2021 03:00 Cluster 4 BBB    Ongoing         3
#13 01/03/2021 04:00 NotActive BBB    Complete        4
#14 01/03/2021 08:00 Cluster 2 BBB    Start           1
#15 01/03/2021 09:00 Cluster 2 BBB    Ongoing         2
#16 01/03/2021 10:00 Cluster 3 BBB    Ongoing         3
#17 01/03/2021 11:00 NotActive BBB    Complete        4
#18 20/02/2021 19:00 Cluster 1 DDD    Start           1
#19 20/02/2021 20:00 Cluster 2 DDD    Ongoing         2
#20 20/02/2021 21:00 NotActive DDD    Complete        3
```

Comment: I can see how your solution works, however, I have found something unforeseen with my data. Can I briefly update my OP to help illustrate?

Comment: I have added in an additional example. I have some UserID's that do not always begin with "Cluster _", but rather, they begin with "NotActive". Please see my updated desired output for more clarification i.e. UserID "DDD". 

Would really appreciate it if you could amend your solution to take this into consideration :) thank you kindly

Comment: @RobinTurkington Try the updated answer.